# How to fit table columns to content

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I created a table and want it to fit size of screen and also borders between cells to fit content. In css i set table with:

```
table-layout: auto 
width: 100%
```

this cause the columns to fit the content but if content of column is long than table gets too wide in screen and some of columns get lost...
I want table to fit the size of the screen?
How can i do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're not going to show us your [mcve] code how are we supposed to help beyond making the simple suggestion of "*use `max-width`*"? How many columns does your `<table>` have? What type, or size, of content?

Comment: columns are added dynamically to table (i'm using primeNg table), it could be maxinum 20 columns and 2 columns are string that could be very long

Comment: So give us a best-case, and worst-case, example of the resulting HTML (showing the HTML after the contents have been loaded).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Css,

```
table{
width:100%;
}
td,th{
width:1%;
}
```

Comment: but now columns not fit the content

Comment: send your design screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the table a max-width of 100%.

```
table {
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

this is hacky way but keep in mind still all must equal to 100%

```
<table style="width:100%">
<tr style="width:25%">
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr style="width:25%">
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr style="width:25%">
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr style="width:25%">
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```